# Regex for telephone System.Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, delphi

I need a regex to extract a phone number from a string in the format (99) 9999-99999 or (99) 99999-9999, tested some more no work out, need it in Delphi using "System.RegularExpressions"

not work

```
(\(11\) [9][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})|(\(1[2-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(\([2-9][1-9]\) [5-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})
```

not work

```
(?:(?([0-9]{2}))?[-. ]?)?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})
```

Ps: I not found in any search that works exactly.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: also : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+telephone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
\(\d{2}\)\s(\d{4}-\d{5}|\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{4}-\d{4})
```

https://regex101.com/r/zF2cH0/2

Comment: `(99) 99999-9999` - work `(99) 9999-9999` not work, I tested in Delphi and http://regexr.com/ is almost!

Comment: (99) 9999-9999 isn't listed in your matching cases in the question. I've edited my regex above to allow it.

Comment: work `\(\d{2}\)\s(\d{4}-\d{4}|\d{5}-\d{4})`

Comment: Yes that one works for 2-4-4 and 2-5-4 formats, but not for 2-4-5.  The regex I posted above works for all three.